# Local variables in compile text stream (smalltalk)

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to overwrite the `#new` message in `MyObject`. The problem is that when the text gets compiled, the local variables, `disp` and `oldNew` are changed to `t1` and `t2` respectively (I'm using Squeak 4.3) and then it can't send `oldNew` to `self`.
I could change their names but I'm not sure that's a good idea.
Here's a basic outline of what I have:

```smalltalk
MyObject class methodDict at: #new put:
    (Object compilerClass new
    compile: 'new
        | disp oldNew |
        oldNew := MyObject class methodDict at: #new.
        disp := Dispatcher new.
        ^disp xxxViewedObject: self oldNew'
    in: MyObject
    notifying: nil
    ifFail: []) generate
```

I'm not 100% sure if what I'm doing is the right way to do it so other ideas are welcome.

Edit: OK so I realise now it was looking for `oldNew` as a message in `MyObject`, but then how do I run the compiled method?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my problem was that `MyObject` was a subclass of `ProtoObject` and is now a subclass of `Object`.
Here's the code that seems to work after this change:

```smalltalk
MyObject class methodDict at: #new put:
    (Object compilerClass new
    compile: 'new
        | disp |
        disp := Dispatcher new.
        ^disp xxxViewedObject: self basicNew initialize'
    in: MyObject
    notifying: nil
    ifFail: []) generate
```

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate your new generated compiled method you may use:

```
aCompiledMethod valueWithReceiver: nil arguments: #()
```

That's a nice way, however if you're experimenting problems I wrote a "[code generator](http://www.smalltalkhub.com/#!/~hernan/CodeGenerator)" based in a cross-Smalltalk library called Grease and which can be useful for you. It manages auto-comments, RBParser and Parser, authoring, and basic templating. All can be extended by anyone of course.

Answer (score 0):

Generated methods are no different than others. So you simply send the method's selector to invoke it:

```
var := MyObject new.
```